# How can I access an specific element number in each row in a splited string variable in R

Tags: arrays, r, string, list

Lets suppose I have the following data

data$city_name:

```
New York
Hong Kong
```

I split the string

```
data$city_name_split <- strsplit(data$city_name, " ")
```

Then I've got a variable "city_name_split" like that:

```
..$ : chr "New" "York"
..$ : chr "Hong" "Kong"
```

I want to take al the first parts and put them into a "city_first" variable, the all the second parts and put them into a "city_second" variable, so the output is the following:

```
city_first : chr "New" "Hong"
city_second : chr "York" "Kong"
```

I've tried things like:

```
city_name_split[][1]
city_name_split[[1]]
```

Oh! By the way, I cannot "unlist()" Because some of the elements just have 1 string.

How can I acces all the first elements and put all of them in a variable?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Might be a faster way but:

```
  DT <- list()
  DT$city_name <- c("New York","Hong Kong")
  DT <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,strsplit(DT$city_name," ")))
```

This gives you a data frame with column 1 as First Name, column 2 as Second Name

Comment: It's a little bit messy, but it works. I have to put the result in other dataframe and them put it back in variables. Thank you!